# Чтение\Запись части байт из части файла

Tags: java

Имеем: обычный mp3 файл.
Можно ли считать определенное количество байт, например 128 с конца файла, не читая весь поток байт?
Можно ли перезаписать в конец файла эти 128 байт, не перезаписывая файл целиком?
Можно ли удалить с конца файла 128 байт?

Если да, то как? Это нужно, т.к. хочу написать утилиту для редактирования ID3 тегов. И файлов будет очень много.

Я верно предположил, что если полностью читать-менять-записывать каждый файл, это будет занимать больше времени, чем менять куски данных в файлах?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите теги редактировать, то я бы порекомендовал не писать велосипед, а использовать [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic), чтоб не мучиться с id3v2, id3v1 и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

То что вы хотите можно сделать примерно так:

```
public static byte[] readFileSegment(File file, int index, int count) {
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[count];
    try {
        raf.skipBytes(index);
        raf.readFully(buffer, 0, count);
        return buffer;
    } finally {
        raf.close();
    }
}
```

Ваше предположение верно.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на класс `java.nio.channels.FileChannel`.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.internal.TextListener;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

public class FileChannelExamples {
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    private File file;


    @Before
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        file = tempFolder.newFile();

        // для каждого теста создаем временный файл из 50 байт от 0 до 49
        byte[] data = new byte[50];
        for ( int i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            data[i] = (byte)i;
        }

        try ( FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( file ) ) {
            out.write( data );
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void canReadLastTenBytes() throws IOException {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 4096 );

        FileChannel chan = FileChannel.open( file.toPath(), 
          StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE );
        // чтение в буфер с позиции 40 (последние 10 байт)
        chan.read( buffer, 40 );
        chan.close();

        buffer.flip();

        assertArrayEquals( 
          new byte[] {40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49},
          Arrays.copyOfRange( buffer.array(), 0, 10 )
        ); 
    }

    private static byte[] readFileIntoArray( File file ) throws IOException {
        try ( InputStream in = new FileInputStream( file ) ) {
            byte[] result = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            in.read( result );

            return result;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void canAppendToFile() throws IOException {
        FileChannel chan = FileChannel.open( file.toPath(), 
          StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE );
        // если записывать после конца файла, данные дописываются
        chan.position( chan.size() );
        chan.write( ByteBuffer.wrap( new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ) );
        chan.close();


        byte[] fileContent = readFileIntoArray( file );
        assertArrayEquals( 
          new byte[] {45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
          Arrays.copyOfRange( fileContent, 45, 55 )
        ); 
    }

    @Test
    public void canTruncate() throws IOException {
        FileChannel chan = FileChannel.open( file.toPath(),
          StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE );
        // обрезка файла до 40 байт
        chan.truncate( 40 );
        chan.close();

        byte[] fileContent = readFileIntoArray( file );
        assertEquals( fileContent.length, 40 );
        assertArrayEquals( 
          new byte[] {35, 36, 37, 38, 39},
          Arrays.copyOfRange( fileContent, 35, 40 )
        ); 
    }

    @Test
    public void canOverwriteAndAppend() throws IOException {
        FileChannel chan = FileChannel.open( file.toPath(),
          StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE );
        // при записи, существующие данные перезаписываются
        // если происходит превышение размера файла, данные дописываются
        chan.position( chan.size() - 5 );
        chan.write( ByteBuffer.wrap( new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} ) );
        chan.close();


        byte[] fileContent = readFileIntoArray( file );
        assertArrayEquals( 
          new byte[] {40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
          Arrays.copyOfRange( fileContent, 40, 55 )
        ); 
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InitializationError {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        junit.addListener( new TextListener( System.out ) );
        junit.run( FileChannelExamples.class );
    }
}
```